# If $\tau$ is a stopping time, then $E(X_{\tau})=?$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $\{X_n \in \mathbb{N}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a sequence of r.v. and $\tau_k=\min\{n\in \mathbb{N}:X_n=k\}$

Does $E(X_{\tau_k})=E(k)=k$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes: $$E(X_{\tau_k})=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}P(\tau_k=t)E(X_{\tau_k}\mid \tau_k=t)=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}P(\tau_k=t)k=k.$$

Comment: What if $\{n\in \mathbb{N}:X_n=k\}=\varnothing$?

Comment: @zhoraster in that case there's no stochastic process...

Comment: @MickA That's assuming $P(\tau = \infty)=0$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, otherwise, $X_{\tau_k}$ is not well-defined by what is given.

Comment: There **is** a stochastic process identically equal to $1$. But it never reaches $2$.

Comment: @zhoraster sorry, my mistake, I read the initial set, instead of the set in the definition of tau. Your remark is the same as mine, when I say tau=infinity.

Comment: So strictly speaking $E[X_{\tau_k} \mathbf{1}_{\tau_k<\infty}] = k P(\tau_k<\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use inf not min in the case that we have $\tau_k = \inf \{\emptyset\}$

---

Hint:

1. Show that $\tau_k < \infty$ a.s. (Thus we can use min instead of inf)
2. Note that

$$E[X_{\tau_k}] = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} P(\tau_k = t)E[X_{\tau_k} | \tau_k = t]$$

where

$$E[X_{\tau_k} | \tau_k = t] = \frac{E[X_{\tau_k} 1_{\tau_k = t}]}{P(\tau_k = t)} = \frac{E[X_{t} 1_{\tau_k = t}]}{P(\tau_k = t)}$$

3. Convince yourself that

$$E[X_{t} 1_{\tau_k = t}] = E[k 1_{\tau_k = t}]$$

4. Finally note that

$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} P(\tau_k = t) = 1$$

Note that 2, 3 and 4 make use of 1.